# How to parse a PAC file on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, pac

So i'm trying to get the proxy info on an iOS device. The OS handily provides use with a function CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings() to get a dictionary of the settings. When the host and port are provided I have no issue, I can access them in the dictionary with the kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy, and kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPPort keys respectively. However, sometimes these are not provided and instead a URL is provided for the kCFNetworkProxiesProxyAutoConfigURLString key. Now this is where I'm getting the problem...

So I pull the file, which contains a javascript function as expected:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url,host)

{
    if (isInNet(host, "10.xxx.xxx.xxx", "255.255.224.0"))        
    {                                               
    return "DIRECT";                                
    }
        if (isInNet(host, "10.xxx.xxx.xxx", "255.255.224.0"))  
    {                                               
    return "DIRECT";                                
    }
return "PROXY host:port";   
}
```

which all looks good to me..?

Then, I try to call the function and get the return value, this is where it all goes wrong :( Here's my most recent attempt:

```
NSString *jsFunction = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // jsFunction is the javascript function above
JSContext *context=  [[JSContext alloc] init];
[context evaluateScript:jsFunction];
JSValue *function = context[@"FindProxyForURL"];
JSValue *jsResult = [function callWithArguments:@[[JSValue valueWithObject:[NSString stringWithCppString:host] inContext:context], [JSValue valueWithObject:[NSString stringWithCppString:host] inContext:context]]];
NSString *result = [jsResult toString];
```

And result always comes back as undefined!!

I have tried a few test functions in place of the PAC that just increment numbers and they work as expected, the issue seems to begin when I introduce a call to isInNet. Has anyone had a similar issue? Is isInNet not supported in iOS? Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `isInNet` (or any other PAC function that might be used) is not defined; they are not standard Javascript functions. Have you tried something more straight-forward like `CFNetworkCopyProxiesForAutoConfigurationScript`?